# How to plot label last highest between two point

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

> Can please someone enlighten me with the following uncertainty?

I try to plot a label for the highest value in a buy signal. But I can only plot the highest values at once. Look forward to the help.

```
track_buy = longCondition? true:false
track_sell = shortCondition? true:false

var float highest_buy = 0.0
var float lowest_sell = 10e10

var int bar_buy     = na

//longSignal
//longCondition
if longSignal
    track_buy := true
if shortSignal
    track_sell := true

    
highest_buy := track_buy ? math.max(nz(highest_buy), high) : na   
lowest_sell := track_sell ? math.min(nz(lowest_sell), low) : 10e10

//plot(highest_buy, color=color.purple, style=plot.style_linebr)
//plot(track_sell?lowest_sell:na, color=color.purple, style=plot.style_linebr)


is_high = ta.valuewhen(highest_buy,high,0)
con = is_high>=highest_buy[1]

if con
    label_ = label.new(bar_index, highest_buy[0], text=str.tostring(highest_buy[1] ) , style=label.style_label_down, color=color.new(color.black,80), textcolor=color.black)
```

This is how it looks. it didn't work as expected. Is there a way to draw labels only for the last candle's highest?

[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdTAC.jpg)
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OI2F.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calculating the highest high on each trade when the trade is closed or when it's the last bar, and then get the label on the `bar_index` of when the value happened. For example:

```
lookback = bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(0) + 1

float highest = na
if lookback > 0 
    highest := ta.highest(lookback)

barIndexOfHighest = bar_index - ta.barssince(high == highest)

if (strategy.position_size == 0 and strategy.position_size[1] > 0) or barstate.islast
    label.new(barIndexOfHighest, highest[1], text="Highest! " + str.tostring(highest[1]), style=label.style_label_down)
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i use indicator so i can't use strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(0) function.
So how can I use it? Thank you again.